# Trying to sum aliases for column headings using common table expressions

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, alias, common-table-expression

I have a table of data where passes and fails are recorded over a number of weeks.

I want to count the number of attempts per week, as well as the number of passes and fails, then take a sum of these passes and fails as a check.

```
SELECT week, 
    COUNT (Week) as weekcount, 

    sum(case when result = 'pass' then 1 else 0 end) as 'passcount' ,
    sum(case when result = 'fail' then 1 else 0 end) as 'failcount',
        sum(case when result = 'pass' then 1 else 0 end) +
        sum(case when result = 'fail' then 1 else 0 end) as 'sum'

FROM table1
group by week
order by week
```

The above code snippet does what I want, but I have been reading about CTEs as an alternative to having the repetition in my query.

I want to be able to use the aliases 'passcount' and 'failcount' in my query without adding them as columns to the table. I have attempted to set up the CTE first below.

```
with sums as
(
    select result,
    sum(case when result = 'pass' then 1 else 0 end) as 'passcount' ,
    sum(case when result = 'fail' then 1 else 0 end) as 'failcount',
    from table1 
)
```

The above reports a syntax error near the end closing bracket, but I cannot understand why.

Can anyone shed any light on this or a better way of approaching?

Comment: When encountering an error, it's really helpful if you post it; otherwise we can only guess at why your query is failing. As for the query with your CTE, we appear to be missing some of it. Where is your `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, etc statement after the declaration of the CTE? Without the error and full SQL it's impossible for us to even begin to troubleshoot your problem.

Comment: The error you get is due to the lack of a group by clause in your cte. And I'll note that your CTE is only a fragment of a complete query - it cannot be executed by itself. I'll also point out that you can use the simple form of case (e.g., case result when 'fail' then ...) rather than the search form (e.g., case when result = 'fail' then ...). Be careful of the suggestions. If result can have values other than 'pass' and 'fail', you need to adjust them to handle that correctly. And be sure to test that in your QA process.

Comment: There's a trailing comma after `'failcount',`, which makes the query invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're thinking about CTE, you can do it in one set :

```
SELECT 
        [Week], 
        COUNT([Week]) AS weekcount
    ,   SUM(CASE WHEN result = 'pass' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS passcount   
    ,   SUM(CASE WHEN result = 'fail' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS failcount
    ,   COUNT(*) AS TotalSum
FROM table1
GROUP BY [Week]
```

In SQL Server, you can't reference an alias from the same SELECT such as passcount, weekcount..etc. This is way you need a workaround such as using sub-query, CTE, JOIN, CROSS APPLY, or any other method that will serve this purpose.

Here are some of the common methods :

**Using Sub-query**  :

```
SELECT 
    [Week]
,   SUM(weekcount) weekcount
,   SUM(passcount) passcount
,   SUM(failcount) failcount
,   SUM(passcount + failcount) AS TotalSum
FROM (
    SELECT 
        [Week], 
        COUNT([Week]) AS weekcount
    ,   SUM(CASE WHEN result = 'pass' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS passcount   
    ,   SUM(CASE WHEN result = 'fail' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS failcount
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY [Week]
) D 
GROUP BY 
    [Week]
```

**Using CTE** method :

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT 
        [Week], 
        COUNT([Week]) AS weekcount
    ,   SUM(CASE WHEN result = 'pass' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS passcount   
    ,   SUM(CASE WHEN result = 'fail' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS failcount
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY [Week]
)
SELECT      
        [Week]
    ,   SUM(weekcount) weekcount
    ,   SUM(passcount) passcount
    ,   SUM(failcount) failcount
    ,   SUM(passcount + failcount) AS TotalSum
FROM CTE 
GROUP BY 
    [Week]
```

**Using CROSS APPLY** method : 
Refer to  @Gordon Linoff answer (basic and straight forward).

these are the simplest methods that you can use in your case, You could also use PIVOT in your case, but I didn't mention it for the sake of simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, I think lateral joins (i.e. `cross apply`) is a cleaner approach than subqueries and CTEs.  In your case, you can generate flags *before* the aggregation, so this looks like:

```
select week, count(*) as weekcount, 
       sum(ispass) as passcount,
       sum(isfail) as failcount,
       (sum(ispass) + sum(isfail)) as passfailcount
from table1 t1 cross apply
     (values (case when result = 'pass' then 1 else 0 end,
              case when result = 'fail' then 1 else 0 end
             )
     ) v(ispass, isfail)
group by week
order by week
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need one more Select after parantheses

```
with sums as
(
    select result,
    sum(case when result = 'pass' then 1 else 0 end) as 'passcount' ,
    sum(case when result = 'fail' then 1 else 0 end) as 'failcount',
    from table1 
)
select result, passcount, failcount, passcount + failcount as sum
from sums;
```

Comment: How do I incorporate the week count into this? I thought it would be part of the select function after the parentheses?
Should I have that inside the initial CTE?

Comment: I am also getting an error each time I try a variation on this:
Column 'table1.result' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. This is coming from the first SELECT but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to write both `CASE` expressions, you could just use an `IN`:

```
SELECT Week,
       COUNT(Week) AS weekcount,
       COUNT(CASE Result WHEN 'pass' THEN 1 END) AS PassCount,
       COUNT(CASE Result WHEN 'fail' THEN 1 END) AS FailCount,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Result IN ('pass','fail') THEN 1 END) AS PassFailCount
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Week
ORDER BY Week;
```

Yes, this doesn't show you how to use a CTE, however, the logic is "cleaner" (more succinct) than repeating both `CASE` expressions.